# Excel using confidence intervals when forecasting

Tags: confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction-interval, excel

My understanding is that when forecasting if you want to quantify the level of uncertainty of your model, one would typically use predictive intervals. However in Microsoft Excel, when using the 'Forecast Sheet' tool, it appears to be expressing uncertainty using confidence intervals instead.

Are confidence intervals more suited to the Exponential Triple Smoothing algorithm they use, or is there some other reason?

Comment: The choice of interval is determined by the *question you are asking,* not by the algorithm you use to answer it!  (Given Excel's decades-long history of statistical abuse, though, one would naturally suspect the default was chosen out of ignorance...)

Comment: ah no its probably just a missing feature. But good news, we can calculate prediction intervals based on the CI. You just need to widen the CI by the error standard deviation, which you can estimate in the usual ways.